# How to remove sudden slopes of a function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, smoothing

I keep getting functions, represented as pandas' dataframes, that have an unpleasant singularity like the one on the picture — the red plot is the one I'm having a trouble with, the blue one can be ignored.
[image: The plot]
Is there a way to smoothify the marked part so that it looks like the black curve using scipy or anything else?

Comment: what is the data? how is it computed? does it make sense to remove "*an unpleasant singularity*"?

Comment: Well, it comes from a third party software and I need to smoothify it somehow.

Comment: How about just removing the points around the singularity manually ? As there's probably no way to automatically smooth the left side without destroying the right side, and if you want to remove both the left and right parts of the curve then fitting a straight line using least absolute error is your best bet.